# nvidia-prime does't switch gpu

Tags: graphics, nvidia-prime

In `nvidia-settings` chosen "Intel(Power Saving Mode)". Output of `sudo prime-select intel` is:

```
Info: the current alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-358-prime', 'nvidia-358-prime']
Info: the intel profile is already in use
```

But output from `sudo cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch` is

```
0000:01:00.0 ON
```

Ubuntu 15.10 x64, `nvidia-358` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I switched back to nvidia-355, problem solved.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)